# How can I make an entity as in my case toStrict?

Tags: scala, akka-http

how to use the toStrict for the exception is **Substream Source cannot be materialized more than once**

and here is my source

```
  val fileUploadRote = {
(post & extractRequestContext & entity(as[String])) { (request, textReq) =>
  extractRequestContext {
    formFieldMultiMap { fields =>
      println("There are " +
        s"form fields ${fields.map(x => x._1 + " -> " + x._2.size).mkString(", ")}")
      var companyId = fields.get("companyId").getOrElse(List.empty)
      var subCompanyId = fields.get("subCompanyId").getOrElse(List.empty)

      ....................//File Upload code
    }
  }
}
```

}